# How to connect to the MySQL database in ASP.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Is  there a way to access MySQL database using connection string in ASP.Net application?

```
<ConnectionString>
    <add name="" 
    providerName="" 
    connectionString="" />
</ConnectionString>
```

Comment: This is my very first question in this community. So, do suggest me with any improvements in way of questioning.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you not know what values to provide for name,provider name?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to configure connection string. I'm not sure whether the parameters I mentioned above will exist or not (for MySQL connectivity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first have MySql .Net connector plugin installed in your system.
If you don't have, get it and install it:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Then you can simply define your connection string as below:

```
<add name="MySQLCnn" connectionString="server=[SERVER Address];User Id=[Your Username];password=[Your Password];database=[Database Name]" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Here is a simple code which will help you in through this way: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Use-and-connect-to-MySQL-Database-in-ASPNet-Application-using-MySQLConnector.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this answer is helpful.